# Es2016 import not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have been using webpack and es2015 for my react project, but I want to update to es2016. I thought it would be as easy as using npm to install the new preset and then changing my .babelrc, but when I do my all of my es2015 syntax throws errors. I assume that es2016 is simply not being loaded due to some error of mine.

The exact error thrown is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

This is my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2016']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'css-loader',
        query: {
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

This is my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2016", "react"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

es modules are part of the 2015 spec so you need to include the es2015 preset too. The es2016 preset only includes the `transform-exponentiation-operator` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use es2016 preset, you'll need to **add** it to the presets. According to [babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2016/), ES2016:

> **ES2016**: Only compiles what's in ES2016 to ES2015

So, if you update `.babelrc` like this, it'll transpile correctly:

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2015", "es2016", "react"]
}
```

Or you can add [latest preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-latest/). It'll include es2015, es2016 and es2017 presets.

Another thing: you're setting presets at the `.babelrc` file and in the webpack loader config. You only need to set it in one place.